# Make an activity root without clearing anything

Tags: android, activity-stack

Say, I have A->B->C->D stack. How can I rearrange it to D->A->B->C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no method which can be use to rearrange activities from activity stack. however to solve your problem you can see the launch mode of activity http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

you should also see Intent Flags

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html